# Could not resolve placeholder 'login.serviceProviderKey' when deploying uaa to tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, deployment, cloudfoundry-uaa

I have created a uaa war by following these steps:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa.git
$ cd uaa
$ ./gradlew :cloudfoundry-identity-uaa:war
```

When i deploy the war to tomcat i am getting the following exception

```
[2017-04-19 15:24:20.797] cloudfoundry-identity-server/uaa - ???? [localhost-startStop-1] .... ERROR --- DispatcherServlet: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'identityZoneConfigurationBootstrap' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'login.serviceProviderKey' in string value "${login.serviceProviderKey}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'login.serviceProviderKey' in string value "${login.serviceProviderKey}"
```

I am trying to deploy this on tomcat version 9 running locally and plan to get an AWS instance running with tomcat and deploy uaa on it.

Are there any steps i'm missing when deploying to tomcat? Can we deploy a uaa war to tomcat this way or do i have to deploy it to cloudfoundry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A default configuration is embedded in the war file, you can ask to load it adding to the JVM options :

```
-DLOGIN_CONFIG_URL=classpath:required_configuration.yml
```

Comment: Thank you @mpromonet! I was able to resolve the login key errors by using the required_configuration.yml file